# Is there something special about being born on purim?

Tags: purim

Since in Judaism we have a lot of things made by HaShem that have a certain influence on our lives (like the day of the week in which we were born, the month, the hour of the day that we were born on and so on) I would like to know if there are any insights of being born on Purim.

Comment: Probably some interesting things happen the year of your bar or bas mitzvah if you live in a village.

Comment: there is a mekor to minhag of ....      naming a baby mordechai when bris is on purim.  wonder if same for born